# Why can't I "Edit Personal Settings" for a user in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

[image]

So, as you can see I have no option to change stuff like e-mail, phone, name, etc. when I try to edit user information. The account I'm showing in this image is actually an administrator account.

The user accounts we use in SharePoint are pulled from the accounts on the local machine (which is not using AD, just a workgroup). Is there some service I need to install to get this working, or am I missing something simple.

Comment: Worth moving to Sharepoint.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I wish someone knew an answer to this!  I need it too!  Yes, I think it would be a good idea to move to sharepoint.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @BGM because this question is essentially abandoned, you should ask it yourself on [sharepoint.se]. Thank you!

Comment: Okay. Apparently nobody could offer a good answer!

Comment: Did you migrate your site collection from MOSS 2007? I am getting this same issue with my migrated MOSS 2007 sites, but I also see "Mobile Number" as an editable field. For site collections created in SharePoint 2010, I can edit the fields Name, E-Mail, Mobile Number, About Me, Picture, Department, Job Title, SIP Address.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following:

1. Access the Web Site e.g. http://win-sp using the System Account i.e. an account who is Site Collection Administrators
2. On the Right Hand corner, click **System Account** drop down
3. Click **My Profile**
4. Click **Edit My Profile**

I have tested the same for a normal user and that works perfectly fine.

From the screenshot, it looks like you are under `System Account -> My Settings`